# Iterate List of CustomObject ,filter with condition and set specific Attribute

Tags: java, java-stream

I have problem with filters and setter as mentioned below.

I have my custom class **`A`** and i have list of A as **`list`**.
I want to iterate list and filter with **`a1 = "a2"`** condition and want to set **`a2`** attributes with my custom message.
I am able to do with stream,filter,map and collect function of **`Java 8`**.
I had mentioned code for same as well.

**`list.stream().filter(a -> a.getA1().equalsIgnoreCase("a2")).map(a -> a.toBuilder().a2("New a2 value")).collect(Collectors.toList());`**

When i am trying to print same list again but that attribute is not updated there.

Again when i am assigning this expression with list and try to print it's give me that 1 filtered record, with updated value. But it's not updating my actual list.

Could anyone please guide me?

```
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
    @Data
    class A {
        String a1;
        String a2;
        String a3;


        A(String b1, String b2, String b3) {
            this.a1 = b1;
            this.a2 = b2;
            this.a3 = b3;

        }
    }
    class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {


            A obj1 = new A("a1", "b1", "b1");
            A obj2 = new A("a2", "b2", "b2");
            A obj3 = new A("a3", "b3", "b3");
            A obj4 = new A("a2", "b4", "b4");
            A obj5 = new A("a2", "b5", "b5");

           var list= new ArrayList<A>();
           list.add(obj1);
           list.add(obj2);
           list.add(obj3);    
           list.add(obj4);    
           list.add(obj5);    

list.stream().filter(a -> a.getA1().equalsIgnoreCase("a2"))
                    .map(a -> a.toBuilder()
                            .a2("New a2 value"))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            }
        }
```

I had tried below code and it's working fine. But it will update on single records and break loop.

```
list.stream().filter(a -> a.getA1().equalsIgnoreCase("a2"))
                    .map(a -> {
                        a.setA2("New a2 value");
                        return a;
                    });
```

Comment: Stream operations don't modify your input list. You need to assign the result to some variable. In your example you just ignore the result.

Comment: @Amongalen As i am using same reference while iterating and setting updated value. So it should be updated in my actual list itself.

Comment: Which operation in your opinion modifies the objects? I don't think Lomboks builder modifies objects but creates a new ones instead.

Comment: Nope same `a.toBuilder().a2("New a2 value"))` code works fine if i will use without `lambda expression`.

Comment: The code snippet you've posted in the comment returns an object of type `A.ABuilder`, not `A`. It doesn't modify the `a` object.

Comment: @Amongalen, I had updated my updated code as well, and it's working fine. But it will update only first record and return from it.

Comment: In your example you filter out all elements that `a1.equals("a2")` and just then update the value. In your list only one element fulfills that condition and thus only one is updated.

Comment: But what id 4 or 5 records match with conditions, then that will not get updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

toBuilder() creates a new instance. So you get a new item in a new list when you get to Collectors.toList().

Unless if you do a .setA2() on the original element, you can't update a list like this.

```
// You can reuse the list then.
list.stream().filter(a -> a.getA1().equalsIgnoreCase("a2"))
                    .forEach(a -> {
                        a.setA2("New a2 value");
                    });



// Alternatively, use a method reference
list.stream().filter(a -> a.getA1().equalsIgnoreCase("a2"))
                    .map(a -> {
                        this::update
                    });

private A update(A a) {
    a.setA2("new a2 value");
    return a;
}
```

**Also, do not feel forced to use Streams. You might as well use a for() loop with an if() in it.**

Comment: when i am doint a.setA2(), it's asking me to missing return value; If i will return that `a` itself, my loop will get over there and it will not able to perform this comparison for further elements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the newly created list to a variable, which can be se same used before, but it's going to be a new list with those changes introduced.

To assign it to that same variable just add `list =` before the expresion like this

```
list = list.stream().filter(a -> a.getA1().equalsIgnoreCase("a2"))
                    .map(a -> a.toBuilder()
                            .a2("New a2 value"))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

> that i had already tried, and i am able to get that filter one record list there. But my requirement is to just update value of matching record.

I'm not sure if by `value of matching record` you mean updating the list or keeping the elements of the list and updating the values within those elements. To update the value of the element you could do

```
list.stream()
    .filter(a -> a.getA1().equalsIgnoreCase("a2"))
    .forEach(a -> a.setA2("New a2 value"));
```

There you aren't creating a new list, just updating the value of the elements that pass the filter.

Comment: that i had already tried, and i am able to get that filter one record list there. But my requirement is to just update value of matching record.

Comment: why are you using the builder? do you **need** to instantiate a new `A`?

Comment: **`toBuilder()`** works differently. Only requirement is i just want to update value for matching records.